# django select widget doesnt update when i pass the choices into it

Tags: python, django-models, django-forms, django-views

so im trying to update in my view a select widget as part of a form.

i'e seen tons of stuff on how to do it, i've followed it and got nearly there.
i've got a bit of code below which is called to populate the select with the choices and it does, but i think the formatting is out, as its passing back a unicode string and i think it needs to be a tuple.

assigning the choices

```
form.fields['size_option'].widget.attrs['choices'] = Product.get_options(product)
```

the code that generates the choices

```
def get_options(self):
    optionset = "("
    for option in self.optionset.options.all():
        optionset = optionset + "(\'" + option.name + "\', \'" + option.name + "\')"
    optionset = optionset + ")"
    pdb.set_trace()
    return optionset
```

the html generated for the select is below.

```
<select id="id_size_option" name="size_option" choices="((&#39;Small&#39;, &#39;Small&#39;)(&#39;Medium&#39;, &#39;Medium&#39;)(&#39;Large&#39;, &#39;Large&#39;))">
```

so the problem is probably the optionset passed back. i can guess as much. i just don't know whats wrong with it. i cant find documentation that shows how this should be formatted inside the select.

Comment: why are you returning you optionset as a string.....it must be a tuple as in ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196941/how-do-i-add-a-set-of-options-into-a-select-widget/4197054#4197054

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is this supposed to be doing? The format for a list of choices is a standard tuple:

```
CHOICES = (
    ('x', 'choice x'),
    ('y', 'choice y'),
)
```

so I don't understand what you are trying to do with all that string formatting.

Secondly, `choices` is not an element of the widget's `attrs`, it is an attribute of the field and/or the widget itself:

```
form.fields['size_option'].choices = product.get_options()
```

In any case, you probably want to use a ModelChoiceField here, then you can set the `queryset` attribute to the list of options you want.

Finally, you don't call an instance method with `Class.method(instance)`, you call it with `instance.method()` - in your case, `product.get_options()`.

Comment: Daniel, the tuplet will be different for every product, therefore i need to get the tuplet at the time i display the product. hence the rather random string formatting. ive already moved away from this to the following line instead of those 4

    def get_options(self):
        return self.optionset.options.all().values_list('name', 'name')

then it was as simple as fixing the call as you stated above and im working. onto the next issue ;)